# Mount Additional Storage on shared hosting without root access

Tags: linux, mount, hosting, shared-hosting

I have a domain with

- a website where my clients upload files (expected 100GB)
- my employees have emails (3 mail box, 10-15GB each)

My current "shared hosting" is fantastic, and I committed for 3 years. It is fast, and flexible. I want to keep using it. It has 40GB storage.

This is shared hosting, so :

- I am limited as to what I can do,
- but creating a Symlink works
- I have cpanel, terminal access and WHM
- I dont have root access.

The same provider also offers a "storage VPS" with 256 GB storage (on HDD).
Is there any way to mount one of the "storage VPS" folder into my shared hosting drive (e.g. as \home\mywebsite.com\externalDrive)? e.g. with FTP connection, SSH connection, Webdav connection, anything else?

Please don't tell me that I can get the client files uploaded directly to the storage VPS, I know that. I want to see if I can mount it. So maybe I can mount a folder as "\home\mywebsite\mail\mywebsite.com\myemail" and have one of the email box on the Storage VPS as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Nope, not happening. Shared hosting does not offer any such facilities.

Furthermore, even when you can do it (like on a dedicated server where you have root access), transparent network filesystems are often not reliable. They have weird failure modes that can be hard to handle in your application(/website).

You can however simply put (part of) the website elsewhere. That VPS you found, Amazon S3 (or the like), there’s lots of possibilities. This is in fact what you should be doing. Do keep backups in mind.

Putting content elsewhere does not mean you have to let clients access it directly. You can proxy the requests.

Comment: Thanks. How about for the emails? Could I have a tool on the VPS that download the email (POP3 without leaving a copy on the server), then my users access through IMAP on the VPS? Any name of such tool (this is basically a POP3 client but IMAP provider)?

Comment: Sure you can, that’s something many mail providers offer after all. Dunno what this would be called though. On Gmail, it’s called “Mail Fetcher” or sometimes “POP3 Fetcher”. Here’s [a related question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/526300).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have ssh access as you say, and if your VPS server is accessible through that, you can use `sshfs` to mount it on to your desired system. Here are a couple of resources that detail a how-to:

- [SSHFS: How to Mount Remote File Systems Over SSH](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/sshfs)
- [How To Use SSHFS to Mount Remote File Systems Over SSH](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh)

Comment: I cannot install SSHFS because I have not root access. When I just put the SSHFS file, it says I am missing FUSE library, which I cannot install because I have no root access. Or can I?

Comment: Yeah FUSE needs to be preinstalled. I guess I wasn't clear where you wanted stuff mounted. If it's your web server to your VPS server and vice versa rather than say your devs or your work/home PC where you have full access, you'd need to talk to your ISP if they have an integration already between the two since they offer both or if they could install the FUSE library on your instance, since it requires suid.